# Is transaction need to be committed to fire a trigger?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, transactions, spring-transactions

In my application, I am updating a table through Hibernate and there is a UPDATE trigger for that table.
My question is, Do I need to commit that transaction(Spring Transaction) under which this update operation is happening ,
to get the trigger fired ?

I am using Spring transaction and Oracle database

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

No, but Hibernate often waits for transaction to end to run all SQL updates, so it may look that way.

Try flushing your changes using `EntityManager#flush` (JPA api) or `JpaRepository#flush` (from Spring Data) or using `JpaRepository#saveAndFlush` after updating entity.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the database level triggers are fired when the data reaches the disk. That only happens when a commit is done.